# Python: parsing a text input file containing a mix of strings, integers and commas

Tags: python

I'm new to python, though I know a number of other computer languages. The problem is reading in data from a text file with 12 lines in the format:

Jan(7, 14, 13, 9)

one month per line from Jan to Dec (each with 4 integers) so that calculations can be performed on the integers in the data.

The parentheses in the input data are mystifying me, is there an efficient way of extracting the integers from the data file? I could work this out myself eventually, but I'm trying to help someone else and there is a time factor. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [abstract syntax tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) to get a tuple of values

```
>>> import ast
>>> line = 'Jan(7, 14, 13, 9)'
>>> j = line.index('(')
>>> line[:j]  # month
'Jan'
>>> ast.literal_eval(line[j:]) # a tuple of values
(7, 14, 13, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
>>> s = 'Jan(7, 14, 13, 9)'
>>> idx = s.index('(') #find the index of (
>>> idx
3
>>> s[idx+1:-1] #the content of ()
'7, 14, 13, 9'
>>> list(int(x) for x in s[idx+1:-1].split(',')) #now a split and a list comprehension
[7, 14, 13, 9]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that lines has a pattern, as you said.

```
line = 'Jan(7, 14, 13, 9)'

parsed_line = eval(line[3::])

sum_all = sum(parsed_line)
>>> 43
```

It returns a tuple.